# React Native architecture about using threads? How multiple JS backend api calls managed in it?

Tags: multithreading, api, react-native, redux-saga

How react-native is managing threads?

How to achieve good performance without any jerking when executing multiple backend api calls?

Can i create my own threads? And do background tasks like backend api calls?

I have used [apisauce](https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce) with [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) so what happens if i execute many backend api calls simultaneously?

It blocks some times but sometimes app runs smooth.

Answer (score 1):

JS does not have threads. Like you said, if you have many processes going on, then performance will suffer. If you need to do that, I suggest making a native module probably, that way you can actually have threads and communicate with the JS thread that handles the presentation.